# Method and way to highlight the validation message in the web page by using Selenium IDE

Tags: browser-automation, selenium-ide

Is there is any way to highlight the validation message by using Selenium IDE?

Example: During login when the user passes the invalid input the validation messages and login will be failed. I want to highlight the validation message which is getting displayed on the screen.

Comment: What do you mean with Highlight? Select the text with the mouse?

Comment: @NielsvanReijmersdal - Please see my screenshot and help me  - https://www.screencast.com/t/MUa5kqLI5

Comment: I still do not understand what you want to do.

Comment: do you want to make a screenshot of the page and apply a visual highlight? or do you for example want the error text in your log? like `throw new RuntimeExeption("error text")` would do?

Comment: @globalworming,- Yes I want to apply the visual highlight basically highlighting the element feature like below screenshot - https://www.screencast.com/t/QKMJxhQefn8

Answer (score 4):

You can use the "[`run script`](https://www.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/docs/en/api/commands/#run-script)" command with JavaScript code in the target field.

Here some example code to highlight the first `h1` element on a page with XPath:

```
document.evaluate('//h1', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.setAttribute('style', 'outline: red dashed 5px !important')
```

I can't seem to pass found elements with Selenium IDE, so you need to locate in JavaScript code.

Looks something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

<s>When looking at the API of selenium IDE there is no way to do it.</s> https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/38970/35888

If you have access to the webdriver you can visually highlight specific elements by playing around with the css dynamically. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24882723/how-can-i-set-new-style-of-element-using-selenium-web-driver

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
WebElement element = driver.findElement(yourElement);
js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', 'outline: yellow dashed 5px !important')", element);
```

in your case you would want to set the background color of the element.

Comment: I got it working based on your idea to use the JavaScript Executor that is present in the new Selenium IDE :)

Comment: oh, `run script`, didn't see that, nice

Answer (score 0):

I believe that was functionality provided by the old, different version of SelniumIDE before the complete re-write in 2018.

I no longer see that built-in functionality in the new SelenumIDE.